# EWS - Exchange Server - Availability Options

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm using EWS API to work with Exchange Server. I need to use the SuggestedTime feature where based on hte meeting time I provide and the resources (meeting rooms) I want the server to suggest to the me the free times for the meeting based on the rooms free/busy information. However when I'm using the service and requesting the info it is returned but not in an easy format. I have to do a lot of loops to acquire what I need. Based on this link :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh532560(v=exchg.80).aspx

I'd expect that it should returns a list of suggested times directly.

Is there an easier way to get this information ?

Answer (score 1):

Simplified version is presented here: http://www.independentsoft.de/exchangewebservices/tutorial/getavailability.html